# Python tkinter- Saving text and keeping text format

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter plain text editor where the user can save the text as a ".doc" file, opening files, making text bold, underlined etc. When ever I make the text bold and save the file. When I reopen the file, the text isn't bold anymore after that. Is there anything I can do to ensure this happens? 
Let me know if there is any code you would like to see!

Comment: Please provide the widget you're using, and some sample formatting. See how to write a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for additional suggestions.

Comment: Provide the [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dump` method instead of `get`. A short documentation can be found on the following pages - [tcl/tk](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M84) and [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.dump-method).

This way you can save all the user data and formatting information (tags). However, once you load the file you will have to write a code to parse the data and add the proper formatting as there is no automatic way provided.

**EDIT:** Take a look at this simple example:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
    pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello World!")
text.pack()

text.tag_add("hello_tag", "1.0", "1.5")
text.tag_config("hello_tag", background="yellow", foreground="black")

file = open("output.txt","w")
file.write(str(text.dump('1.0', END)))
file.close()

root.mainloop()
```

The `output.txt` looks like this:

```
[('tagon', 'hello_tag', '1.0'), ('text', 'Hello', '1.0'), ('tagoff', 'hello_tag', '1.5'), ('text', ' World!', '1.5'), ('mark', 'insert', '1.12'), ('mark', 'current', '1.12'), ('text', '\n', '1.12')]
```

Each tuple has the information about: `key1 value1 index1`. Your task is to iterate over this array of tuples and insert the appropriate text data or add tag information to the text widget. A full description of the values can be found here: [dump()](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M84)

You said that the output format is `.doc` which stands for MS Word file format. The full description of this format can be downloaded from [Word (.doc) Binary File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx) This is quite complex task to load this format to the Tkinter widget on your own, but the task is the same. You need to read the file and translate the MS Word formatting to the one you use in your application.

Comment: Thanks for that, how would I end up doing that?